# Input Elements have no margin (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I created a Fiddle of my Problem (however in Fiddle it is displayed correctly).

https://jsfiddle.net/rjf8tsbk/1/

As you can see, i have a form with 4 inputs. Whenever i execute this on Webstorm, the website is displayed in chrome but ALL inputs have NO margin (no space). I copied my code to `jsfiddle` and its looks correct. I wonder if i have an error in webstorm or could this be an error within bootstrap?
This is a picture how it looks like normal : [image]

EDIT (HTML CODE)

```
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">LearnYou</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-success ">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-success ">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

EDIT 2:
Looks like the problem comes from "Jade", whenever i execute simple html5 it is rendered correctly but when i use Jade it is displayed wrong.Any Ideas?This my Jade Code:

```
 nav(class="navbar navbar-inverse")
        div(class="container")
            div(class="navbar-header")
                button(type="button" ,class="navbar-toggle collapsed" ,data-toggle="collapse", data-target="#navbar", aria-expanded="false" ,aria-controls="navbar")
                    span(class="sr-only") Toggle
                    span(class="icon-bar")
                    span(class="icon-bar")
                    span(class="icon-bar")
                a(class="navbar-brand" ,href="#") LearnYou
            div(id="navbar",class="navbar-collapse collapse")
                form(class="navbar-form navbar-right", role="form")
                    div(class="form-group")
                      input(type="text", placeholder="Email", class="form-control")
                    div(class="form-group")
                      input(type="password", placeholder="Password", class="form-control")
                    input(type="submit", class="btn btn-success" ,value="Sign in")
                    input(type="button", class="btn btn-success", value="Sign up")
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.form-group {
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Hello Gavin, this is a solution yes, but i am looking for an solution without adding external css, since the html is rendered correctly in jsfiddle

Comment: Would be difficult to give a definitive answer without seeing the rest of the styles.

Comment: there are no other ressource except importing bootstrap and jquery

Comment: Are the DIVs being displayed inline like this? https://jsfiddle.net/rjf8tsbk/3/ `</div><div class="form-group">`

Comment: yes, but i dont have the structure you said but it looks exactly the same

Comment: Seems like there is a similar discrepancy when your code is rendering. The correct thing to do would be to add a margin to the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

To apply margin you can use mx  class

```
<div class="form-group mx-2">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
</div>
```

for margin right and left in the same time or you can use **mr-2** (margin right) and **ml-2** (margin left)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap `v5` dropped form-specific layout classes in favour of existing grid and utility classes. Using legacy classes with v5 will no longer produce the expected styling from previous versions — such as the `form-group` margins. See the form section in the [Migration To v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms) guide for more info.

The [v5 form examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/overview/#overview) now use margin utility classes, which should produce the desired result. These classes should provide an easy solution without the need for custom styling rules.

Example:

```html
<form>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```